# Changing bounds of double integral while converting from cartesian to polar form

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, upper-lower-bounds

> Evaluate the  integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\sqrt{π}} \int_{y}^{\sqrt{π}} \cos(x^2) \ \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y $

I have replaced $x^2$ with $r^2\cos^2(θ)$ but could not change the bounds by using inequalities.

Comment: Change the [order of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)) instead.

Comment: Consider the triangle formed by $x=y, y=0, x=\sqrt \pi$ and change the order of integration. $$\int_{y=0}^{y=\sqrt \pi}\left(\int_{x=y}^{x=\sqrt \pi} \cos x^2\ \mathrm{d}x\right)\mathrm{d}y$$$$=\int_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt \pi}\left(\int_{y=0}^{y=x}\cos x^2\ \mathrm{d}y\right)\mathrm{d}x$$$$=\int_0^\sqrt\pi x\cdot \cos x^2\ \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: @SumantaDas I just saw your comment after I posted my answer... this is a complete answer:) can you please post that as an answer? I will delete mine.

Comment: That is fine. No problem. (+1) from mine.

Answer (score 2):

Going off of the hint given by azif00 and completing the work done by sumanta we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x=y}^{x=\sqrt{\pi}} \cos(x^2)dxdy &= \int_0^\sqrt{\pi}\int_{y=0}^{y=x}\cos(x^2) dydx \\
&= \int_0^\sqrt{\pi}\left[y\cos(x^2)\right]_{y=0}^{y=x}dx \\
&= \int_0^\sqrt{\pi}x\cos(x^2)- (0\cdot\cos(x^2)) \ dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi x\cos(u)\frac{du}{2x}  \tag{substitute $u = x^2$}\\
&= \frac12\int_0^\pi\cos(u)du \\
&= \frac12\Big[\sin(u)\Big]_0^\pi \\
&= \frac12 (0 - 0) \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
Note that it often helps to draw the region over which we are integrating:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are integrating over triangle bound by $y = 0, x=y, x = \sqrt {\pi}$ so changing the order your integral becomes

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\sqrt{π}} dx \,\int_{0}^{x} \cos(x^2) \, dy$

Now you can use substitution $x^2 = t$ for your second integral.

Answer (score 0):

If it is obligatory desire to use polar coordinates, then  $x=r \cos \phi, y= r \sin \phi$ gives
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
0 \leqslant x \leqslant \sqrt{\pi} \\
0 \leqslant y \leqslant x
\end{array}\right\} \to \left\{\begin{array}{l}
0 \leqslant r \cos \phi \leqslant \sqrt{\pi} \\
0 \leqslant r \sin \phi \leqslant r \cos \phi
\end{array}\right\}$$

First of equations gives restriction for radius $r \leqslant \frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{\cos \phi}$ and second for angle $\phi \in [0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$, so we have

$$ \int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{π}} dx \int\limits_{0}^{x} \cos(x^2)dy=\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{\cos \phi}}r\cos (r^2 \cos^2 \phi) drd\phi$$

Though, changing order of variables, without polar coordinates, seems to be more good way, but boss is Boss.